# What program is intercepting a specific keyboard combination?

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard, remapping

How can I figure out which software has globally redefined a key combination on my system?

I finally hunted down the Intel driver that decided to install itself today and commandeer a slew of everyday key combinations, so that wasted time is behind me. But this is not the first time this kind of thing has happened, so I would like to be able positively identify who is getting what keystrokes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For around $15 [HotKey Commander](http://hkcmdr.anymania.com/) will tell you.

There is a trial version which you can try to make sure it works for you.
(I read once that Windows allows you to detect which hotkeys are used, but not which application has registered the hotkey. If that is true, then this program may be using some un-documented calls, which is why I recommend trying before buying).

It worked for me under XP.

Update. Didn't work for me on Windows-7.

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice looking app. It distinguishes between system-wide and application-specific, and it even shows the icon for each app. To bad the display window cannot be resized, and the columns are not sortable. -- The culprit in my situation is an exe in system32, but a quick google revealed enough about it to be able to find it in Control Panel.

Comment: Note that its companion utility "Hotkey Explorer" is free. It provides the same detection & summarizing, without the configuration & overriding functionality.